# What is the installation order to add new language pack to an existing SharePoint farm?

Tags: 2010, 2013, upgrade, installation, language-pack

I'm running an existing SharePoint 2013 (SP2010 should work the same) farm on a typical 3 tier topology. 1 WFE, 1 APP and 1 SQL.

I'm running on Windows Server 2012 R2 English. SharePoint Server base install files are SharePoint 2013 with SP1 English. I added the German language pack during the initial installation. After that I've "upgraded" to the November 2014 CU. Installation order on WFE, APP and Search:

1. Prerequisites
2. SharePoint 2013 with SP1 (EN)
3. Language Pack for SharePoint 2013 with SP1 (DE)
4. November 2014 CU (Global)

Once the binaries were installed I created the farm and configured the services. The farm is up and running in a health state.

I now got new requirements and after a final approval I agreed to install one new language pack (French = FR) on the environment.

Our normal process would be to install in the following order for WFE, APP and Search:

1. Language Pack for SharePoint 2013 with SP1 (DE)
2. November 2014 CU (Global)

After the installation I would run PSCONFIG on each box sequentially.

The question I have is related to best practice vs. supported.

**Do I need to reapply the November 2014 CU after I added the new language pack to be in a supported state?** Does the language pack override artifacts from the later CU? I think I know what is best practice and I know I'm on the save side of the fence, but do we really need to reapply the CU? It sounds a little theoretical but I really want to understand if the lower version software (language pack) will override higher version software (cu).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need the November CU after installing the LPs Because CU contains the fixes for Language packs and it update the language related files as well. Their is no separate CU for language packs, Only SP1 are separated.

So, when you running the Nov CU then you dont need to worry about the override thing.

- Language Pack for SharePoint 2013 with SP1 (DE)
- November 2014 CU
- ReRun the Config Wizard with default settings.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3a8704de-d606-40b1-aa43-b565f4c14212/sharepoint-2013-language-pack-installation-is-operating-system-language-pack-install-required?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. I was not asking about best practice. I need to know if this is supported. I'm not worried about overwriting files if the update is the highest "version". I'm concerned about a farm with a CU post SP1 and then apply a language pack. The language pack is lower than the CU. Are the CU files are deployed for all languages even at that point the languge was not present. MUST i reapply the latest CU valid for the farm. Thank you for your effort.